# Substitute regex match groups where match groups may overlap

Tags: python, regex, string

I am working in Python. I have a String that matches my regex and would like to substitute all the match groups (The end goal is to wrap each group in an HTML  span).

I know there are good ways to do this with the re module however I don't know if my case can be handled with that since I know some of my matches overlap.

I've looked at the re module and String templates but I don't think either help me in this situation. I've also tried implementing a solution myself but I've yet to have any luck with that and it feels like there should be a better solution.

E.g. Let's say I have the String:

```
"This is my cat her name is Alice"
```

and I'm using the pattern:

```
"This is my cat (her name is (\w+)).
```

In this case I should have:

```
match 0: "This is my cat her name is Alice"
match 1: "her name is Alice"
match 2: "Alice"
```

I want to end with something that looks like this

```
"This is my cat <span class=\"class1\">is <span class=\"class2\">Alice</span></span>
```

Comment: `This is my cat her name is` is a fixed text? If no, how do we genericly distinguish the match 1 from the text before? And which other verbs can we have in addition to "to be"?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your question. This was just an example, the regex pattern could be anything. I don't actually know the regex pattern prior, it is handed in from a file. I can get all the Match objects I need, the problem is that if I try to insert at a specific position, because the position changes every time I add a "span" I have to account for the new additions. This is manageable when the match groups are separate but when they overlap like the case above it is very difficult to determine where I should be inserting new text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a list of indices where groups begin and end. You can use the [`.start([group])` and `.end([group])`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.start) functions for this. (Make sure you have some way of distinguishes group starts from group ends.)
2. Sort the list by descending index.
3. For each index in the list, insert `</span>` if it's an end index or `<span class="whatever">` if it's a start index.

Code:

```
match= re.match(p, s)
indices= sorted([(match.start(index),True) for index,group in enumerate(match.groups(),1)]+ \
                [(match.end(index),False) for index,group in enumerate(match.groups(),1)], reverse=True)
for index,is_start in indices:
    if is_start:
        s= s[:index]+'<span class="class1">'+s[index:]
    else:
        s= s[:index]+'</span>'+s[index:]
print s
# output: This is my cat <span class="class1">her name is <span class="class1">Alice</span></span>
```